# Maximal Minimum Spanning Tree by Removing $k$ Edges

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

The problem is as follows:

> Consider a connected, undirected, and weighted graph $G = (V, E, w)$ and an integer $0 < k < |E| - |V| + 1$. Describe and analyze and efficient algorithm to remove *at most* $k$ edges from $E$ such that the resulting graph $G' = (V, E' \subseteq E, w)$ has a maximal weight minimum spanning tree over all possible $G'$.

I initially thought a greedy algorithm would work with "just remove the $k$ smallest edges as long as the graph remains connected." However, this does not work, consider the following graph and $k = 1$:

[image: graph]

The MST of $G$ has weight 9. If we remove the minimal edge $(B, C)$, the MST of the resulting graph has weight 12. However, if we remove the edge $(A, B)$, the MST of the resulting graph has weight 13. So this greedy strategy does not work.

---

Other strategies, we can first note that it only helps to remove edges that are in the MST of $G$ initially. So we can first determine $T = MST(G)$. The next (inefficient) thing we could do is consider each edge in $e \in T$ and do:

1. Remove $e$ from $T$, cutting $T$ into $T_1$ and $T_2$.
2. Determine the next smallest edge $e'$ spanning $T_1$ and $T_2$ in $G$.
3. Keep track of $e$ such that it maximizes $w(e') - w(e)$.

Repeat this $k$ times. This doesn't seem very efficient though. This would be something like $O(k \cdot n \cdot (n + m))$ I think. We could optimize this a bit by keeping track of an ordered set of edges on the cuts.

I am wondering if there exists an algorithm that is $O(km \log n)$ or better. Any approaches / advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Could we get the most helpful hint, that is, is this problem created by yourself or did you find the problem somewhere?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Created by me and some other TAs. No online source that I know of (I've tried looking for it).

Comment: @Apass.Jack I have good news! (Maybe?) I was informed that the problem was actually proposed in a competition a while ago (see [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/minimum-spanning-tree/practice-problems/approximate/worse-mst/)). However, the accepted solutions aren't necessarily optimal based on the scoring method listed. Also, there is no editorial :(

Comment: @Apass.Jack after reading through a handful of solutions, it appears the best solution on there just brute-forces the whole problem quickly. That is, they compute the MST after removing each edge, then repeat this $k$ times. So this is not very helpful. Correction, there are a couple solutions that use the greedy strategy I recommended, which I guess is probably a good heuristic.

Comment: What do you mean by "Determine the next smallest edge $e'$ spanning $T_1$ and $T_2$ in $G$"? Anyway, I think the approach is wrong since the problem is NP-hard  as shown in my answer.

Comment: In fact your second strategy is also greedy and does not work . The best removals for k=2 do not necessarly contain the best removal for k=1.

Comment: @xskxzr, the edge $e$ is the edge connecting $T_1$ to $T_2$ in the MST, by removing $e$, the _next smallest edge_ $e'$ that connects $T_1$ and $T_2$ would be the one that replaces $e$ if we remove $e$. Thus, my goal was to maximize this difference in weight.

Comment: @Vince, I see that now, similar to how removing a larger weight edge would force a greater difference in the weight added, we could apply the same thing. Where removing two larger weight edges would increase the weight even more. This could be shown by "isolating" a node, connect it by $k$ large weight edges, then connect it by one _really large_ weight edge. Thus, we would want to remove the $k$ large weight edges instead of any smaller weight edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as the $k$ most vital edges for the minimum spanning tree problem. It has been proved as NP-hard [1].

For fixed $k$, Weifa Liang proposed an $O\left(n^k\alpha((k+1)(n-1),n)\right)$ algorithm where $\alpha$ is a [functional inverse of Ackermann’s function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse) [2], and can be improved to $O\left(n^k\log\alpha((k+1)(n-1),n)\right)$ using Seth Pettie's sensitivity analysis [3].

---

[1] Frederickson, G. N., & Solis-Oba, R. (1999). Increasing the weight of minimum spanning trees. *Journal of Algorithms, 33*(2), 244-266.

[2] Liang, W. (2001). Finding the k most vital edges with respect to minimum spanning trees for fixed k. *Discrete Applied Mathematics, 113*(2-3), 319-327.

[3] Pettie, S. (2005, December). Sensitivity analysis of minimum spanning trees in sub-inverse-Ackermann time. In *International Symposium on Algorithms and Computation* (pp. 964-973). Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg.

Comment: Thanks for this! Ironically enough, Frederickson is one of my professors. I should've asked him about this!